# data.table way to create new column based on on other columns

Tags: r, data.table

I'm compiling results from some webinars and have a `data.table` consisting of three columns - email address, if they attended the webinar and if they listened to the recording (`emails`, `webinar`, `recording`):

```
# recycling is intentional here 
> dat <- data.table(emails = letters[1:10], webinar = c('yes', 'Yes', 'no', 'yes'), recording = c('Yes', NA, 'NA'))
> dat
    emails webinar recording
 1:      a     yes       Yes
 2:      b     Yes      <NA>
 3:      c      no        NA
 4:      d     yes       Yes
 5:      e     yes      <NA>
 6:      f     Yes        NA
 7:      g      no       Yes
 8:      h     yes      <NA>
 9:      i     yes        NA
10:      j     Yes       Yes
```

I want to add a new column `score` that has a value of 2 if either `webinar` or `recording` are `Yes` or `yes` and 1 otherwise.

With the above sample data, I'm able to get the desired output by:

```
> dat[, score := ifelse(tolower(webinar) == 'yes' | tolower(recording) == 'yes', 2, 1), by = .(emails)]
> dat
    emails webinar recording score
 1:      a     yes       Yes     2
 2:      b     Yes      <NA>     2
 3:      c      no        NA     1
 4:      d     yes       Yes     2
 5:      e     yes      <NA>     2
 6:      f     Yes        NA     2
 7:      g      no       Yes     2
 8:      h     yes      <NA>     2
 9:      i     yes        NA     2
10:      j     Yes       Yes     2
```

However, on my actual dataset the same logic fails:

```
              emails webinar recording score
  1: email_redacted1      No      <NA>    NA
  2: email_redacted2     Yes      <NA>  TRUE
  3: email_redacted3      No      <NA>    NA
  4: email_redacted4     Yes      <NA>  TRUE
  5: email_redacted5      No      <NA>    NA
 ---                         
204: email_redacted6      No      <NA>    NA
205: email_redacted7      No      <NA>    NA
206: email_redacted8      No      <NA>    NA
207: email_redacted9     Yes      <NA>  TRUE
208: email_redacted0      No      <NA>    NA
```

I've removed the emails manually for privacy reasons but the dataset on which this operation was performed is a `data.table` and has the same 3 columns as the above example.

I do get some warnings in the console:

```
50: In `[.data.table`(retdat, , `:=`(score, ifelse(tolower(webinar) ==  ... :
  Group 88 column 'score': 2.000000 (type 'double') at RHS position 1 taken as TRUE when assigning to type 'logical'
```

My current workaround is as follows: set `score` to 1 initially and then use "i" in `data.table` to set it to 2 if either condition is met:

```
dat$score <- 1
dat[tolower(webinar) == 'yes' | tolower(recording) == 'yes', score:= 2]
```

Questions:

1. I don't quite get why I get different results with  my sample data and actual data (both data.tables with the same structure)
2. What is the preferred `data.table` way of getting my desired output (shown with the sample data)

Comment: Try replacing ifelse with fifelse

Comment: If emails column is unique then try replacing ifelse with if construct

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not the same as your actual dataset because your condition in `ifelse` is always `TRUE` or `FALSE` but in actual dataset it has `NA` values also (`TRUE | NA = TRUE, FALSE | NA = NA`). Check `?ifelse` for more details about `NA` and result type. Basicly this happend:

1. first value of vector `tolower(webinar) == 'yes' | tolower(recording) == 'yes'` is `NA`
2. if value is `NA` in `ifelse` function will return `NA` to its position in result
3. because first value in result is `NA` your result vector will be `logical`

Also you can remove `by`, its not needed for this kind of operation.

Comment: Thanks, I realize that now, I'll add a filter to remove the `NA` values. I'm using the `by` argument because the data has many duplicate emails and I want to keep only one entry per email.